# pr2_computer_monitor with lm_sensors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to create a similar node as the [pr2_computer_monitor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_computer_monitor), but I do not have access to a computer with IMPI (as I would assume most people don't have).  I was wondering if anyone has written a similar monitoring node with [lm_sensors](http://lm-sensors.org/), which is something that just about every computer is capable of running.

I am mainly interested in temperatures, voltages, and fan speeds, as my robot runs in a high-temperature, battery operated environment (Alabama in the summer).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9069/pr2_computer_monitor-with-lm_sensors/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not yet tried it, but I believe you use the pr2_computer_monitor as an example to build a package that will pull information from stdout and stderr of a given command.  If you look in the bottom of nvidia_smi_util.py, you can see how to execute a commmand and pull its output.  It launches: `sudo nvidia-smi -a`, so you could change that to an lm_sensors command that that outputs your desired temperature reading.

Also, there is a package called [nvidia_gpu_monitor](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=nvidia_gpu_monitor), but I have not tried it.

---

Originally posted by [evanmj](https://answers.ros.org/users/47/evanmj/) with karma: 250 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-15**:
We would be interested in such a package. Please post an announcement on ros-users if you get something ready to publish (or test).

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-15**:
Perhaps I'll branch off of the pr2_computer_monitor package and make a more generic one for lm_sensors.  I figured that it was possible, but I was trying to save a bit of work on something that is far from critical for our project.  Thanks for the help.